# Can I safely heat stainless steel 1-2 inch ball bearings in a consumer microwave?

Tags: dielectric, microwaves

I am looking to heat 1 or 2 inch stainless steel spherical ball bearings in a microwave. I would like the bearings to get to about 140 degrees F but not hotter. I have read that this should be fine as long as there are no edges which of course there isn't. Also, will different grades of steel heat up differently? I am not sure how to control the temperature as they may get too hot too quickly. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for safety recommendations.

Comment: Put them in a bath of water of the right temperature. Microwaves heating of metals is a terrible idea - both because of skin effect (you would only heat the surface because of the frequency) and the potential risk of running a microwave that is essentially "unloaded" (in the RF sense of the word). Why would you want to do this? If you could rephrase your question in terms of the physics of heating metals in a microwave, it might be interesting and on topic.

Comment: just google "metal in microwave".

Comment: This can be done safely outside. Only thing you might overload your microwave. I've played with microwaves and it takes much effort to make one dangerous.